# Make multer upload an asyc function

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await, multer

I am trying to upload image as a user is registering how do I make upload 'async'? because I need the respose of user creating i.e want to use await as follows

```
const user = await db.User.create(req.body);
```

the following is my code:

```
const upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: fileFilter 
}).single('upload'); 


exports.user_register = async (req, res, next) => {
try { 
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        try {
            if (typeof req.file === 'undefined') {
                **const user = db.User.create(req.body);**
                const {id, username} = user;
                res.status(201).json({id, username});               
            } else {

                    .
                    .
                    .
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The upload function has the same format as your user_register function, so you can simply have an async "next function" as well.

```js
...
upload(req, res, async (err) => {
...
```

However, I would suggest separating the upload middleware from the user registration function.
You can still access the "file" attribute from there.

So, you export both the "upload" and "user register" functions.

```js
exports.handle_upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: fileFilter 
}).single('upload'); 


exports.user_register = async (req, res, next) => {
try { 
  if (typeof req.file === 'undefined') {
      const user = await db.User.create(req.body);
      const {id, username} = user;
      res.status(201).json({id, username});               
  } else {
    ...
  }
  ...
 };
```

And then in your express router you can call both functions in sequence:

```js
const { handle_upload, user_register } = require('...');
...

router.post('/registeruser', handle_upload, user_register);
...
```

Comment: Thanx Elio .. the thing is this, I have many routes so I separated them with their logic into two different scripts. That's the reason upload is inside user_register. If maybe I could just convert upload function into an async function that would solve my problem.

Comment: You can try to wrap the upload function in a promise, but I'm not sure that will help you. Something like:
`function promiseUpload (req, res, next) {  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => upload(req, res, error => error ? reject(error) : resolve())  );`
And then call this function inside the user_register function.